# VS 2013 Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlParser, Version=13.0.0.0

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2013, clr

I have some SQL CLR projects I created with VS 2012.  I want to open them with VS 2013, so I installed SSDT 16.5 for VS 2013.

Now, I am getting this error opening the SQL CLR projects:

> Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlParser, Version=13.0.0.0

Thanks for any ideas

Answer (score 3):

I also faced this issue, Installing SQL Server 2017 broke SSDT. I have fixed the issue, Here is how I was able to fix it
Steps

1. Uninstall Microsoft SQL Server 2017 TSQL Language Service.
2. Install TSqlLanguageService.msi from SQL Server 2016. Part of Microsoft® SQL
   Server® 2016 Feature Pack - https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=52676 (Version:13.0.1601.5 File: ENU\x64\TSqlLanguageService.msi)

then restart visual studio and reload the project

Comment: The link is broken but your solution worked using this: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=56833

Answer (score 1):

Installing a newer version of SQL Server Management Studio can break SQL Server Data Tools. You need to downgrade the TSQL Language service to 2016 (13.0.0.0) level.

Originally from here:

https://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/1921984/Microsoft-Visual-Studio-Could-not-load-file-or-assembly-MicrosoftSqlServerManagementSqlParser-Versio

> Installing SQL Server 2017 broke SSDT. I have fixed the issue, but
>   just wanted to post this because I couldn't find the solution at
>   first. Steps
>
> ```
> Uninstall Microsoft SQL Server 2017 TSQL Language Service.
> Install TSqlLanguageService.msi from SQL Server 2016.
>     Part of Microsoft® SQL Server® 2016 Feature Pack - https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=52676
>     Version:13.0.1601.5
>     File: ENU\x64\TSqlLanguageService.msi
> ```
>
> I hope this helps someone.

Answer (score -1):

https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/3106613/net-exception-could-not-load-file-or-assembly-microsoft-sqlserver-sqlclrprovider-13-100-0-0-after-installing-sql-server-2016

Client applications should not be using the assemblies from the Program Files folders unless they are from the specific SDK folders (such as "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\130\SDK")

The 13.100.* version of assemblies you are seeing are currently only for use by Microsoft tools and so are not placed with all needed dependencies being in the same place. The DTS folder especially has only a subset of SMO assemblies since that code does not need things such as SqlClrProvider.

Please use either the assemblies from the SDK folders or from SharedManagementObjects.msi to use as references for your applications.

Comment: I do not have a reference to Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlParser in my project.